# Defer vs Deference

Tags: meaning

From [wiki] https://wikidiff.com/deference/defer, I see the derived term of defer is deference.

Why doesn't deference also mean to delay or postpone?

For example, in this problem:

His premiership, seemingly cast-iron year ago, is now so vulnerable that even a good day at the office does no more than buy him a few weeks of ____ from rebels within his own party.

A. controversy

B. reproach

C. respite

D. relief

E. blame

F. deference

The answer was C&D but I chose C&F because I thought deference was a more appropriate term than relief in this case.

Comment: You did know that 'defer' has more than one meaning?

Comment: Derived terms often have specific meanings that aren't as broad as the root they come from.